# Android Gradle Build tries to access JCenter even though I have not configured it anywhere

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bamboo, jcenter

Our Android builds are running on our company's CI build agents. These don't have internet access and must fetch all their Maven dependencies from the virtual repositories in our Artifactory.

I now noticed that all builds are taking a few minutes longer than on my PC and apparently the delay comes from Gradle trying to access JCenter:

```
build   01-Apr-2019 11:56:44    11:56:43.449 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://jcenter.bintray.com:443
build   01-Apr-2019 11:56:44    11:56:43.452 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to jcenter.bintray.com/18.195.111.75:443
build   01-Apr-2019 11:56:44    11:56:43.452 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to jcenter.bintray.com/18.195.111.75:443 with timeout 30000
build   01-Apr-2019 11:56:44    11:56:43.453 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connect to jcenter.bintray.com/18.195.111.75:443 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
build   01-Apr-2019 11:56:44    11:56:43.454 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to jcenter.bintray.com/35.156.75.35:443
build   01-Apr-2019 11:56:44    11:56:43.454 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to jcenter.bintray.com/35.156.75.35:443 with timeout 30000
```

Of course, this can't work, but Gradle seems to be retrying this over and over until it finally gives up. The build then works anyway because all the dependencies are available in Artifactory...

This is how we currently configure our repositories for Gradle:

```
repositories {
    def artifactoryBaseUrl = "https://artifactory.somecompany.com"
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryBaseUrl}/libs-release-local"
    }
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryBaseUrl}/google-maven"
    }
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryBaseUrl}/fabric-maven"
    }
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryBaseUrl}/maven-central"
    }
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryBaseUrl}/gradle-plugins"
    }
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryBaseUrl}/jitpack-maven"
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's no mention of JCenter at all - how does Gradle decide that it wants to access it and is there any way I can disable this?

I see this somewhere further up in the log but don't know where it comes from:

```
build   01-Apr-2019 11:40:23    11:40:22.351 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.ResolvedArtifactCaches] Creating new in-memory cache for repo 'BintrayJCenter' [1dd858de07b774d6be9d3e38c5646087].
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle builds only have one default repository: the Gradle plugin portal for resolving Gradle plugins, which is only available for resolving build script `classpath` dependencies and not project dependencies.

If you see your build trying to access JCenter, then a imported build file or plugin is most likely the source of that.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you! I now found out that this particular issue is only manifesting itself on some of our build agents but not on others. Even though the BintrayJCenter repo is configured on all of them, only some are actually trying to access it...

Comment: Since both the name and URL of the repo in our case match the constants defined in `DefaultRepositoryHandler` (`public static final String DEFAULT_BINTRAY_JCENTER_REPO_NAME = "BintrayJCenter"; public static final String BINTRAY_JCENTER_URL = "https://jcenter.bintray.com/";`) the repo was most likely added by using the shortcut method `jcenter()`, right? Is there any way find out which plugin is to blame?